# Magento 2: How to sort products by price then by name?

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1, sorting, simple-product

The reason I'm asking this is that all my products have configuration and I have to display only simple products (configurable products not visible). However when I sort by price, the products belongs to the same configuration got scattered all over the place. **After sorting by price, I want to sort my product by name within the same price range**. Is this achievable?